# Codeigniter + Nginx must render 404 page provided by framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx, http-status-code-404

So, I have next problem. This is my nginx config

```
server {
    disable_symlinks off;
    listen       80;
    server_name  g9tv.loc;
    charset utf-8;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /home/dejmos/www/g9tv;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }


    error_page  404              /index.php;
    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /home/dejmos/www/g9tv;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        root           /home/dejmos/www/g9tv;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /home/dejmos/www/g9tv$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

When I go to page that not exists on server I got 404 page provided by nginx, but I need to get 404 page provided by codeigniter show_404() function.

Comment: There is a file under application/config called routes.php where you can edit the 404 page such as $route['404_override']  = 'welcome';

Comment: If I use Apache Codeigniter render own 404 page. If I use Nginx it renders nginx-404 page. That is a problem. Custom 404 pages also not works

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. It caused by subfolder. I place Codeigniter to root folder and all ok now.